# Retrieve individual values along with their sum?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that contains link_ids that relate to another table; and this table has column titled ammount that stores values typed int. To retreive some total ammount along with individual values I query it as follows:

```
SELECT ip, ammount, (SELECT SUM(ammount) FROM stats WHERE link_id = $link_id) as total_ammount FROM stats WHERE link_id = $link_id
```

Here's values in the stat table:

```
stat_id, ip, ammount, link_id
1, 211.126.197.45, 10, 3 
2, 61.158.167.84, 7, 3
```

So, I need to retrieve the total ammount for link_id along with its individual ammounts:

```
$total_ammount == 17;
$ips[0]['ammount'] == 10;
$ips[1]['ammount'] == 7;
```

Something like that... The question is whether the query is alright or it might be better (how to make it better)?

Comment: "Ammount" just happens to be a very common misspelling of the word "Amount". No problems, though. If you've misspelled it in your code, you might or might not want to fix that, though. Depends on how much work it would be. It might confuse other developers, though. Or just put a big grin on their faces. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html):

```
SELECT stat_id, SUM(ammount) AS amount
FROM stats
WHERE link_id = 3
GROUP BY stat_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Result:

```
stat_id  amount
1,       10    
2,       7     
NULL,    17
```

Or you can use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT stat_id, ammount AS amount
FROM stats
WHERE link_id = 3

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, SUM(ammount)
FROM stats
WHERE link_id = 3
```